# Убрать слова в квадратных скобках

Tags: python

У меня есть текст, полученный программой, и **он выглядит следующим образом**:

> Тысячу лет [1 сноска] я бродил по лесу в поисках [2 сноска] наживы.

**Мне нужно получить:**

> Тысячу лет я бродил по лесу в поисках наживы.

Как это можно максимально рационально сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте регулярные выражения.

```
import re
txt='Тысячу лет [1 сноска] я бродил по лесу в поисках [2 сноска] наживы.'
print(re.sub("\[.*?\]", "", txt))
```

Comment: В большинстве случаев мне выдается ошибка: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: У вас точно тип str? если нет, то сделайте явное преобразование к str. Еще проблема может быть в специальных символах. см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727583/re-sub-erroring-with-expected-string-or-bytes-like-object